# Regular expression password strength

Tags: regex

I have written a regular expression which could potentially be used for password strength validation:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)\_])(?=.{6,})^\S*$/
```

My password criteria is as below:

- at least 6 characters
- no space
- at least one digit
- at least one uppercase
- at least one lowercase
- at least one special character: !@#$%^&*()_

This is expected output:

```
FooBar123!           should match
foobar123!           should not match (no upper-case letter)
FooBar123            should not match (no special character)
F0bar! F0bar!        should not match (contains spaces)
Fo0*                 should not match (too short)
```

For some reason all the tests passed except FooBar123! . Any idea why is it like that? Thank you.

Comment: What programming language do you use? Regex is really not suitable for the password validation - or at least not at once, but partially step-by-step.

Comment: It's much easier to split this into a few regexes, it becomes complex (an really for no reason aside being clever) to stuff it all into one line

Comment: Works for me in JS https://regex101.com/r/PreitU/2.

Comment: The rules: "no space", and "at least one special character (from your list)" are bad practice. Why add such arbitrary restrictions to the rules? Let the user enter whatever they want. A "special character" could be `£`, or `}`, or `漢`, or .

Comment: `[!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)\_]` hurts the eye. Can make it `[!@#$%^&*()_]`. Don't need the extra `^` at the end, already have one at the beginning. Count assertion can be combine with not whitespace `\S{6,}$` Rewritten is `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_])\S{6,}$`. Even still, yours works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below regex and the condition can be implemented over the response of this expression

`^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)\_])(?=.{6,})^\S*$`